# Why is my border misaligned?

Tags: posters

**Question**

I am using a background image that has a black border of equal thickness all the way around it (which I created and saved as an .eps file).

In my LaTeX document, however, I cannot seem to get the border to appear in equal thickness all the way around the image. How can I solve this?

**Minimum Working Example**

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0b,final]{a0poster}

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}

\newcommand{\background}[3]{
\newrgbcolor{cgradbegin}{#1}
\newrgbcolor{cgradend}{#2}
\psframe[fillstyle=gradient,gradend=cgradend,
gradbegin=cgradbegin,gradmidpoint=#3](0.,0.)(1.\textwidth,-1.\textheight)}

\newenvironment{poster}{
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.95\textwidth}}{
\end{minipage} 
\end{center}}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
\put(10,-50){
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,
keepaspectratio]{TheSun2.eps}\vfill}}}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPic}

\begin{poster}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

**Note**

My image is a .eps file - I'm not sure how to upload this (or whether it's necessary).

My background image is a photo with a black border round it. I took the photo and put it in Inkscape, then made a black border round it, with equal thickness round each side. I specified the thickness mathematically. In Inkscape, the border looks uniform. In Texmaker, it is obvious that the border is non-uniform (with the above MWE at 100% zoom):

[image]

Comment: well it looks as if your image is clipped at the right hand side but impossible to tell without seeing the page dimensions and the image.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In order to not have my border clipped, I have to go into Inkscape and make the image smaller on the page (even though trying to export the image, not the page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 \usepackage{epsfig}
```

Is just for compatibility with the old (1980's) `epsfig` package syntax. You are not using that syntax anyway so you should use

```
 \usepackage{graphicx}
```

Where did these numbers come from

```
\put(10,-50){
```

Are you sure you are not clipping part of your borders off the page?
You are scaling the image to the full paper width so you have to be *very* accurate in the positioning of the image, if it is out by a fraction then the borders will be different widths. I don't know the `eso-pic` package but they don't seem very natural numbers to me.

Comment: The background image of my poster doesn't cover the entire LaTeX page (i.e. there is some white space beyond the black border of my image). I chose (10,-50) by eye-balling the white space on all four sides of my poster and trying to make them about the same (so that my poster would sit 'in the middle' of the page).